# How do I navigate to sabnzbd.ini in Debian?

Tags: debian

I need to locate this file, and apparently it's in ~/.sabnzbd/. Total Linux newcomer here, how do I access that file?

Comment: On the command line or in nautilus?

Comment: Command line considering that may be the first time in my life I've heard that other word.

Comment: Nautilus is the graphical file explorer included with gnome, which is probably the desktop manager you're using.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is the command to 'change directory'.  So open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/.sabnzbd
```

Now you're in that directory. To see the files, use `ls`.  You'll probably want to see and/or edit the file, for which you'll probably want to use `gedit`

```
gedit sabnzbd.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not really an *answer*, but a lengthy post, too lengthy for the comment box...)

Oh, you could probably use some "Introduction to UNIX" quick tutorial, just to get used to the basic concepts.

For a start: `~` usually denotes your "home directory" (each user is assigned a directory in the filesystem, frequently under `/home/`, but there's no enforced rule on this (other than a ["Filesystem Hierarchy Standard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which may be an interesting read if you're not used to UNIX filesystem and its top level directories).

Opening a terminal emulator (`xterm`, `Terminal`, ...) will give you a shell.

All UNIX programs, shells included, are in a specific directory when they are running, and may change to another directory. When you start terminal emulators, shells usually start at `~`.

Like kevin said, now you can use `cd` to change that directory in the shell. If the file is right under `~/.sabnzbd/`, you can just do *something* with it.

Shells can be used to start programs, and can also be used to do file manipulations. If you just need to read the file, you can use a [*pager*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager), such as `less`:

```
less sabnzbd.ini
```

When you're done, hitting `q` will quit `less`. If you want to edit the file, you need to use an editor, and there are plenty of those. As I have the feeling that, right now, your priority is to edit the file, just try what Kevin suggested.

You can specify *paths* in the shell, not just the name of files in the current directory. You can also do

```
less ~/.sabnzbd/sabnzbd.ini
```

As soon as you get to the shell.

Depending on your system, you may even have a "run command" feature that, if you input `~/.sabnzbd/sabnzbd.ini`, will try to open the file in some editor.

Some shells also have tab completion, try writing

```
less ~/.sabnzbd/sab
```

and hitting the tab key after the b.